# knockout data from AJAX call doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I am fairly new to knockout and trying to figure out why the following won't work. For some reason my returned data from the ajax call is not being translated into an array.

I have a function that returns some JSON

```
bankingApi.client = (function () {

var getSafeFloatCash= function getSafeFloatCash() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/BackOffice/Banking/Banking/GetSafeFloat',
        type: 'GET'        
    });
}
    return {
        getSafeFloatCash : getSafeFloatCash
    };
})();
```

The function returns the following JSON:

```
[{"Denomination":"1p","Value":34.1200},{"Denomination":"2p","Value":98.0400},{"Denomination":"5p","Value":85.0500},{"Denomination":"10p","Value":571.2000},{"Denomination":"20p","Value":62.8000},{"Denomination":"50p","Value":57.5000},{"Denomination":"£1","Value":441.0000},{"Denomination":"£2","Value":398.0000},{"Denomination":"£5","Value":260.0000},{"Denomination":"£10","Value":320.0000},{"Denomination":"£20","Value":780.0000},{"Denomination":"£50","Value":350.0000}]
```

I set up my observable array

```
(function () {

var BankingViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.safeFloatDenominations = ko.observableArray();

    var safeFloatCash = bankingApi.client.getSafeFloatCash();
    self.safeFloatDenominations(safeFloatCash); // does not work!

    self.safeTopUpValue = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = self.floatRecommendedValue - self.safeFloatTotal;
        return total.toFixed(0);
    });        
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new BankingViewModel();        
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);        
});

})();
```

If I paste the values returned from the ajax call into an array variable it works fine, so there is some issue translating the function call into an array.

and this is the view

```
  <div class="row" data-bind="visible: safeTopUpValue()>0, foreach:     safeFloatDenominations">
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" />
    <label data-bind="text: Denomination"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not assigning the data returned from the ajax call to the `observableArray`.  You're assigning the _promise_ returned from `$.ajax` to it instead.  You'll need to use a callback method somewhere along the way to actually get the data from the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on my comment, `$.ajax` doesn't return data - it returns a *promise*.  You need to use that to actually get the data out:

```
var safeFloatCash = bankingApi.client.getSafeFloatCash();
safeFloatCash.done(function(d) {
    //may need to parse the data:
    //d = JSON.parse(d);
    self.safeFloatDenominations(d);
});
```

Comment: This makes sense. Think I still need to put it in a function that is called somewhere then?

Comment: @jazza1000 No - just swapping out the code in my answer for your two original lines should work